# curl 302 redirect not working (command line)

Tags: bash, curl, scrape

In the browser, navigating to this URL initiates a 302 (moved temporarily) request which in turn downloads a file.

> http://www.targetsite.com/target.php/?event=download&task_id=123

When I view what is actually happening via Chrome network tools I see that the redirect is going to a dynamically generated path that cancels itself immediately after download. In other words, even if I know that full path I will not have time to manually call it.

So, how in using the command line can I mimic the browser actions?

I tried

> curl --cookies bin/cookies.txt -O -L "http://www.targetsite.com/target.php/?event=download&task_id=123" --compressed

but this just returns gibberish. The goal of this is to programmatically download this file without having to navigate to the site. Unfortunately I cannot share the site here as it is behind a log-in.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to supply the `-L` or `--location` option in order to enable `curl` to follow HTTP redirects.

Quoting from `man curl`:

```
   -L, --location
          (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the server reports that the requested page has
          moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header
          and  a  3XX  response code), this option will make curl redo the
          request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or
          -I, --head, headers from all requested pages will be shown. When
          authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials  to  the
          initial  host.  If a redirect takes curl to a different host, it
          won't be able to intercept the user+password. See  also  --loca‐
          tion-trusted  on how to change this. You can limit the amount of
          redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.

          When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain  GET
          (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with
          a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response
          code  was  any  other  3xx code, curl will re-send the following
          request using the same unmodified method.
```

Comment: My apologies. -L is the option I tried not -R (I corrected above). It just seems to return gibberish (literally non-ascii strange characters).

Comment: @user2029890 Did you try omitting the `--compressed` option to see if it has any effect?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I modified the original question to show the full curl command which includes cookies -L and -O. I'm not sure if I structured this correctly. Also, in your quote from the manpage it says that authentication is not followed on redirect. Can that be my problem as this is after authentication?

Comment: @user2029890 Did you see the `--location-trusted` option?

Comment: The --location-trusted does not seem to change anything as I'm using the cookie jar. Upon further inspection with -O it downloads a text file containing all the gibberish. It appears as if this gibberish contains info about the files being downloaded. It's a .zip file that contains .jpgs. Perhaps I just need to specify the download format differently?

Comment: Issue is resolved. I just had to structure the command like  curl --cookie /bin/cookies.txt -L -o foo-dev.zip "http://www.targetsite.com/target.php/?event=download&task_id=123". Thanks for all your help

Comment: @devnull's answer is the one that actually worked. If I wanted to theorize about the "correct way to use curl" I wouldn't have come to StackOverflow.

Comment: Just an FYI but the "gibberish" that you were seeing was most likely the contents of the file that is automatically downloaded. If you don't specify `-o <filename>` it will just give you the response data dumped to the console. You can either redirect that data into a file with `<curl stuff> > output.file` or use the `-o` parameter like you are doing now.

Comment: In addition to `-L` modern curl has `--post301`,`--post302`, and `--post303` to use `POST` instead of `GET` after the redirect.